# How to serve Google Big Query output to a client web

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have exported Firestore collections to Google Big Query to make data analysis and aggregation.
What is the best practice (using Google Cloud Products) to serve Big Query outputs to a client web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides seven [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) for BigQuery. You can take any library and write a webserver that will serve requests from client web application. The webserver can use a GCP service account to access BigQuery on behalf of its clients.

One such sample is [this project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery). It's written in TypeScript. Uses NodeJS library on the server and React for the client app. I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to have an express tour through [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/overview), looking for the main [*features*](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/data-studio/benefits/) what this [Google analytics](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/analytics/) service can offer for the customers. If your aim stands for visualizing data from Bigquery, Data Studio is a good option, thus it provides a variety of informative dashboards and reports, allowing the user customize charts and graphs sharing them publicly or via user collaboration groups.

Data Studio spreads a lot of connectors to different data sources, hence you can find a separate [*Bigquery connector*](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370296) for further integration with data resources residing in Bigquery warehouse.

You can track for any future product enhancements [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467?utm_source=in-product&utm_medium=feature-panel&utm_campaign=whats-new).